# ListInterpolation start from zero index:

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, interpolation

we have a Listinterpolation:

```
f = ListInterpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]
```

that gives

```
f[2.5]
2.4375
```

so, ListInterpolation starts from f[1] not from f[0],is there any way we can start it from f[0] instead of f[1]?

Comment: to make sure I understand, you want `f[0]=1` and likewise to continue for the other values?

Comment: You can either add an argument to ListInterpoloation indicating the domain you want to use, or you could use just Interpoloation and provide it with the coordinates.

Comment: Hello. The answer is right there in help. You can do   `L = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}; f = ListInterpolation[L, {{0, Length[L] - 1}}]` and now `f[0]` gives `1`

Comment: it's in the document: "specifies the domain of the grid from which the values in array are assumed to come."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing you can do

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5};
f = ListInterpolation[data];
g[x_] := f[x + 1];
```